# Mongodb Search geolocation with text filters and group by in a single query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, latitude-longitude

[image] We are using Mongo database for insert jobs related data. I want to get the count according to GEO location coordinates with text search on title and description fields.

Suppose we have records

```
id title                   coordinates[0]       coordinates[1]
--+-----------------------+---------------------+----------------
1  PHP developer          | 97.77               | -92.99
2  Laravel developer,php  | 97.77               | -92.99
3  python                 | 97.77               | -92.99
4  Rails                  | 23.77               | -34.99
5  Python, php            | 23.77               | -34.23
```

User search with "PHP" (title), latitude-longitude coordinates and specific with distance 50 miles, If the distance came in first 3 records id[1,2,3] and PHP title came in first two records id[1,2] then user will get result as a count 2. How can we make a query for this in mongo database or PHP mongo database driver query? We are going to attach our database structure as an image. If you have any query let us know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Strange, I don't see any php code?

Comment: You'll want to use aggregation, for it.  Mongo likes to use the `$` and double quotes.  so you'll want to escape the `$` with a backslash '\' like this  `"\$field"` otherwise php will think its a variable.  Sorry I am at home so I don't have any Mongo Examples handy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Mongodb/Driver/Query it can be used like this

```
    $queryString = [
                    [
                        '$geoNear'=> [
                        'near'=> [ 'type'=> "Point", 'coordinates'=> [-73.86, 41.07 ] ],
                        'distanceField'=> "dist.calculated",
                        'maxDistance'=> '5000',
                        'includeLocs'=> "dist.location",
                        'num'=> 10000,
                        'spherical'=> true,
                        'query' => ['title'=> ['$regex' => 'sales' ]]
                        ]
                    ],
                    ['$unwind'=> '$loc'],    
                    ['$group'=>['_id'=> '$loc', 'count'=>['$sum'=>1]]],
                    ['$project'=>['res'=>['loc'=>'$_id', 'count'=>'$count']]], 
                    ['$group'=>['_id'=>null, 'total'=>['$sum'=>1], 'data'=>['$addToSet'=>'$res']]],
                ];
     $conn = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://username:password@localhost:2702/admin");
     $command = new \MongoDB\Driver\Command([
                'aggregate' => 'collection_name',
                'pipeline' =>  $queryString 
            ]);

    $result = $conn->executeCommand('mongodbname', $command);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.crawled_jobs.aggregate([{ "$geoNear": {"near": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [  -73.86,  41.07  ]  },"spherical": true,"maxDistance": 500000,
 "distanceField": "distance","query": {"title": /php/}}}])
```

Comment: Thanks @Rob to ans my question, If i remove this {"title": /php/} then your query is working fine.  I want to run query as mysql like operator  "title like %PHP%" But It behave like "where title = php "  and we want count from group by clause. Please let us help.

Comment: @The Rohan Sanap we want count with group by and  i want to search title with like operator .

Answer (score 0):

check this sardar ji :

db.hotels.find({  "$text": { "$search": "test" },  "location": {        "$geoWithin": {            "$centerSphere": [[               72.867804,               19.076033            ], 5000 ]        }    }})

Answer (score -1):

I think you need this :

db.crawled_jobs.aggregate([ {     $geoNear: {        near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [-73.86, 41.07 ] },        distanceField: "dist.calculated",        maxDistance: 100000,        includeLocs: "dist.location",        num: 1225,
        spherical: true,        "query": {           "title": /sales/
        }     }   },    {$unwind: '$loc'},       {$group:{_id: '$loc', count:{$sum:1}}},    {$project:{res:{loc:'$_id', count:'$count'}}},     {$group:{_id:null, total:{$sum:1}, data:{$addToSet:'$res'}}}    ])